# Showing values in many2many field dependiing selection of another many2many field

Tags: odoo

I am creating a module(OpenERP 7.0) in which i have taken 2 fields both are many2many. First field is related with res.partner.category and second field is res.partner, what i have to do is-
after selecting categories in first field second field should get updated with partners of respected categories
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

write an on change method on the first field which will search the partners related to selected categories and fill them in second field.

Comment: Thanks for answer...I have got partner ids respected to selected categories (using on change method) and records from res.partner, but i am confusing about how to fill them in second field, can you please show it with sample of code

Comment: check the on change event of taxes in invoice line, it is based on similar type of logic.